# Java "Could not find or load main class" (PATH and CLASSPATH Already Set)

Tags: java, windows, cmd, console, system-variable

I'm having issues running java on the command line. I have checked lots of other questions and none have solved my problem.

I am using `Windoze 10 x64`.

Installed at `C:\Program Files\Java`, I have the following files:

`jdk1.8.0_121` and `jre1.8.0_121`.

I already set the `JAVA_HOME`, `PATH` and `CLASSPATH` as follows:

- `JAVA_HOME as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121`
- `PATH as %JAVA_HOME%/bin`
- `CLASSPATH as %JAVA_HOME%/lib`

This is the **current** configuration of the system variables. I tried lots of variations for the configs but none seem to help. Such as adding to the PATH `%JAVA_HOME%\jre1.8.0_121\bin` as well. Nothing seems to help.

If I run `java -version` and `javac -version` they will go through, showing the current version installed.

I can also compile, for example: `javac HelloWorld.java` succesfully.

When I try `java HelloWorld`, I get `Could not find or load main class HelloWorld`.

Here is the `HelloWorld.java` file:

```
    public class HelloWorld{
        public static void main(String [] args){
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    }
```

I spent +2 hr trying to figure this out. I'm sure it's a rookie mistake but honestly, I'm just trying to set this up so I can start learning Java.

**I can run java using `IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition`'s console but not directly on CMD.**

I would really appreciate if you could walk me through like LI5, I really looked for the solution, watched videos on how to set the system variables but it yield nothing.

If you need any more information I'm happy to provide it, thank you.

---

EDIT: Okay, the issue was solved. Thanks to @azurefrog and @mirmdasif for helping me figure it out.

As you can read [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)and below this on azurefrog's comments and mirmdasif's reply, you need to add the current working directory to the `CLASSPATH`.

Add the current working directory to the `CLASSPATH` by adding a `.`(dot) to the `CLASSPATH`.

So `CLASSPATH` should look like this instead: `.;%JAVA_HOME%/lib` (Notice the `.` followed by the semi-colon `;`.

Comment: Can you share your HelloWorld.java file

Comment: Sure, sorry for not adding it. Syntax seems good to me, though... Adding it right now.

Comment: That's the entirety of your HelloWorld.java? No package statement?

Comment: I tried adding a package statement, it didn't work. If you provide me with a better code sample to test, I will be happy to try it. As I said, I am trying to set this up in order to start learning and practicing, so I have little to no idea what the package statement is for. 
Thank you!

Comment: The second thing that pops into my head is that you don't have `.` (the current working directory) on your classpath. Try running `java -classpath . HelloWorld`

Comment: If you take a look at [How should I set CLASSPATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017833/how-should-i-set-classpath), you'll notice it's got `.` prepended to the lib entry, which I don't see in yours.

Comment: @azurefrog `java -classpath . HelloWorld` Works! I will try adding the `.` to the CLASSPATH!

Comment: Thank you, azurefrog and mirmdasif for being so patient. I really appreciate your help. The issue has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `CLASS_PATH` variable.

> The preferred way to specify the classpath is by using the -cp command line switch. This allows the CLASSPATH to be set individually for each application without affecting other applications

Default value for ClassPath variable is **'.'** which means only the current directory is searched. If you specify the classpath variable the default will be overridden.

If want to set classpath as environment variable you may do as running the following cmd in cmd prompt(remember the dot in the beginning)

```
C:> set CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\lib\*
```

For further information http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: The command would not solve the issue but I set the classpath manually to `.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\lib\*` and it does the job! Thank you !

Comment: Actually I am doing the same just from the command prompt

Comment: I tried it from the console but it would not change it. Maybe the System Variable window was open so it could not access it or something like that. 
Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens. You should try to find **java.exe** in `C:\Windows\System32`, if it there you need delete it.

Example: [Java Windows7 System32 folder java.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21412853/java-windows7-system32-folder-java-exe)

Comment: Theres no java.exe in System32! :( But `java -classpath . HelloWorld` works. Seems Im misconfigured the `CLASSPATH`

Answer (score 0):

Just keep updating your Enviroment Variables in classpath whenever you get: 
Error: Could not find or load main class XXX

Then browse to
 C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181